# How to earn the Vox Populi badge,

Tags: bug, support

The Vox Populi badge is described as :"Use the maximum 40 votes in a day".
However I tried to get this one a couple of times now and I never got to more than 31 votes. Then I get the message "You have used all your votes for today".
It looks like a bug to me or there should be a requirement to have "XX question votes up/down votes" or a rep of ZZ to get to 40 votes?

As to the "usefulness of the badge"
Well ... how useful are the badges anyway :-s.
I see a benefit in "appreciating other peoples effort" by upvoting answers and questions (and somehow in downvoting as well). After all this is a questions and answers site and not a discussion forum.

For those willing to give it a try. It is quite some work to find 40 questions/answers worthy to upvote in a day.

Comment: You need to _only_ vote 40 questions (not answers) within one UTC day.

Comment: Och ok. Thanks for the clarification. With the current quality of questions this badge is not an option for me.

Comment: Downvotes count as part of the 40.

Comment: 40 Downvotes is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 30 votes per day. This is the limit.

And in addition to that, you get an **extra 10 votes** on questions. [Read this blog post to find out why](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/).

> You can vote **30** times per UTC day. You get an additional **10** votes on questions only.

I stumbled accross this little detail at the [down votes privilege](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) help page. So if you can only vote 31 times, try if you still can vote on questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
I won't go through the trouble of testing and then see it is undone again :-(

Comment: Just don't vote on a single user more than 2-3 times. You can go through the hottest questions for instance and vote on posts you like with at least 25% votes on questions.

Answer (score 0):

I should warn you that if you up-vote too many answers in a day (particularly made by the one person) the system thinks you are vote-rigging and reverses the votes. I don't know the limit, but I suggest that you don't just find a single user you like and up-vote 40 of their answers. Or even two users.

> how useful are the badges anyway ...

I think they are just to encourage you to do things you might not otherwise bother with, like editing questions or answers to make them better.

---

Also see [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: Just out of interest, I got -170 rep yesterday for the reason "Serial voting was reversed". :)

Comment: That was probably a result of my actions :-(
I thin I'll just forget about stack exchange. We are not compatible.

Comment: No real harm done. I'm just back to where I started two days ago. As for the Vox Populi badge, it sounds like one of the harder ones to get because of all the voting rules. They are designed to stop voting abuse, but can be frustrating for genuine users.

Comment: I spend a couple of days reading questions and answers to vote for good ones (not only your answers but based on author because it is easy and because some authors just give better answers).   
It seems that stackexchange does not appreciated my effort and reversed my work. So I'm not happy.